# Conditionally `collectLatest` or `collect` behaviour on kotlin flow

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have a following problem: there are two types of events:

```
enum class Event {
  REGULAR,
  URGENT
}
```

These events are sent to `val eventsFlow = SharedFlow<Event>` (or channel), where later they're being processed by collector:

```
scope.launch {
  eventsFlow.collect { event ->
     delay(100) //process event (same logic)
  }
}
```

What I want to achieve:

- `REGULAR` events should not cancel processing (if new `REGULAR` event arrives and the collector is busy, processing should not be cancelled, like with standart `collect`)
- But if `URGENT` event arrives, it should cancel processing of current event (like `collectLatest` would do)

So I need to come up with some solution, was trying to play around with `flatMapLatest` and other operators, but getting no luck

Comment: If URGENT event comes while another URGENT event is being processed, should the previous one get cancelled?

Comment: Also, should REGULAR be processed after the URGENT that cancelled it? I ask because normally you collect all REGULAR events, but in this case one of them would be entirely skipped.

Answer (score 0):

```
scope.launch {
    var job: Job? = null
    eventsFlow.collect { event ->
        when (event) {
            Event.URGENT -> job?.cancelAndJoin()
            Event.REGULAR -> job?.join()
        }
        job = launch {
            delay(100) //process event (same logic)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note this will cancel only the single last REGULAR. If we emit 5 REGULAR items and one URGENT, then first 4 REGULAR will be processed normally and only the last one will get skipped. Although it is not entirely clear from the question whether such behavior is expected or not, I would guess it is not.